# Handling two interrupts occurring at the same time for different producers

Tags: embedded, c++, freertos

So I have a UART IRQ handler that is fired for each byte sent over UART, which then writes to a Fifo buffer and once the end of the data is detected, a callback is invoked which parses the data and signals the Main Thread to do stuff based on what's passed.

A few questions:

- If I have two producers that use UART for sending data, how should the situation of the interrupts from each producer occurring at the same time be dealt with? Say, the data is sent from producer A and producer B around the same time, given both are of the same priority, one of the interrupts will take the lead, and when it's done, the second one shall begin. Is this how it actually works?
- If it works as described above, I foresee the FIFO buffer getting "corrupted" in the sense that it could contain alternate characters from each producer assuming interrupts get fired at the same time or in an alternate sequence, as opposed to a whole word from each source separately. I guess the only way around would be to have FIFOs one for each source?

For e.g:

1. Producer A wants to send `"He"`
2. Producer B wants to send `"Hi"`

Both end up sending a byte at the same time

```
UART IRQ -> receives `'H'` from `Producer A`
UART IRQ -> receives `'H'` from `Producer B`
UART IRQ -> receives `'e'` from `Producer A`
UART IRQ -> receives `'i'` from `Producer B`
```

now the FIFO looks like -> `HHei` as opposed to `He` and `Hi` being processed separately.

- If there are multiple producers for the Fifo buffer, and assuming an ISR is triggered for each byte entered/sent, would there really be a need for mutex protection?

**For reference, [here's an example](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v14.0.0%2Fble_sdk_app_nus_eval.html) of how nordic sends bytes from 2 producers, and each triggering the same IRQ:**

1. via a COM listener
2. via UART BLE Service.

Following is just an example for the context...

```
// main.cpp
Uart uart;

int main(void) {

  SystemTsk systemTsk(&uart);
  vTaskStartScheduler();    
}

// systemTsk.cpp
SystemTsk::SystemTsk(Uart &uart) : uart(uart)
{
    systemTaskQueue = xQueueCreate(queueSize, itemSize);
    if (systemTaskQueue == NULL)
    {
        // error handling
    }

    // create a task
    if (xTaskCreate(SystemTsk::run, "main", 256, this, 0, &taskHandle) != pdPASS)
    {
        // error handling
    }   
}

void SystemTsk::run(void *instance)
{
    auto pInstance = static_cast<SystemTsk*>(instance);
    pInstance->mainThread();
}

void SystemTsk::mainThread()
{   
  int data;
  while(true) 
  { 

     if (xQueueReceive(systemTaskQueue, &data, 0) == pdPASS) {
         // delegate stuff according to data
     }
    
  }
}
// uart.cpp
void UARTE0_UART0_IRQHandler(void)
{
   uartObj.irq();
}
   
void Uart::irq(void)
{ 
   // read into buffer etc
   if (endOfData) 
   { 
     uartCb(buffer);
   }
}

// uart_data.cpp
void parse(uint8_t buffer[])
{
  // parse the uart data...
}

void uartCb(uint8_t buffer[])
{ 
   // ...
   parse(buffer);
   // send the data to the queue to unblock the task via xQueueSendFromISR()

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "at the same time"?

Comment: say the bytes are sent from two producers at the same time

Comment: (1) So, let us say, you have two ears, and two guys shout at you "at the same time". But your little head  has only one brain, so it cannot entertain two ears at the same time. Now what should your poor brain do? (2) Another case is that you have only one ear, and the two guys shout at you single ear "at the same time". Practically, one guy should arrive at your single ear 1 pico second sooner than the other. Usually the ear listens to the first guy, check that it is not priority VIP, so go check the later guy, if found high priority, then entertain this VIP, and go back to the non VIP later.

Comment: Well, the messages must be treated as atomic. Constructed then sent in their entirety. But your description of how everything works is not totally clear to me. It sounds like you are using the uart for inter-process communication on a single system. That seems odd to me. Maybe a block diagram would help make things more clear.

Comment: I guess what it comes down to is that the producers must somehow be prevented from talking over each other. Something like a queue could help with that. The main problem is that I can't visualize how your system is organized, neither software nor hardware.

Comment: Just pick a MCU with DMA. Manual rx interrupts from UART was always an annoying thing to deal with. Otherwise, the standard way is to use a ring buffer per UART, protected from race conditions. The ISR should do nothing but to fill this up, with a minimum of code.

Comment: Just to make things clear: You have two systems producing multi-byte messages, potentially "at the same time". And these messages are received by the single consuming system, the code of which you are showing. Is that correct? -- If so, as a side note, how does your hardware work? You cannot simply "merge" the electrical signals. -- Do these two producers have a connection? Can they be synchronized in some way?

Comment: Are you asking about transmitting or receiving?  Should the first sentence say "fired for each byte _**received**_ over UART?  What is a producer?  Are the producers in a different device from the receiver or is there just one device containing both the producers and receiver?  If the producers are in a different device, is it one device or two?  If the producers are two different devices do they connect to a single UART on the receiver or two UARTs?  If there are two receiver UARTs then there should be two FIFOs and if there is a single UART ISR then it should sort which UART made the request

Comment: @thebusybee - currently, I only have one producer sending bytes but eventually I would want to integrate BLE through something like a nordic's NUS application (or I create mines) that emulates a serial port over BLE. So I was thinking about the handling this edge case where bytes are sent over BLE and terminal around the same time...or even when one producer is not even done when the second one decides to send. I could have different pins for each producer, but wouldn't they still fire the same IRQ?

Comment: @kkrambo - RXing and TXing both. 1)Two producers: one sending bytes from a terminal over putty/minicom. Second: bytes sent BLE which would be handled by the UART IRQ handler as it's received. nordic has an example but I wanna try it design my own if feasible https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v14.0.0%2Fble_sdk_app_nus_eval.html

Comment: "...but wouldn't they still fire the same IRQ?"  No, probably not.  Typically each UART has its own IRQ.  In your example code, the name `UART0_IRQHandler` suggests the existence of `UART1_IRQHandler`, `UART2_IRQHandler`, etc.  But even if all the UARTs do share an IRQ then there must be some way for the ISR to lookup which UART requested the interrupt.  Then the ISR can use that lookup to determine which FIFO to put the received byte into.

Comment: I tried running nordic's example and I see the same IRQ is fired :) and yeah maybe there's a way to lookup who initiated the interrupt

Comment: I don't have the nordic example source code.  But I suspect that data is received via BLE and then _transmitted_ via the UART to the terminal.  And in the other direction data is _received_ from the terminal via the UART and then transmitted via BLE.  The same IRQ is used but in one case it is transmitting and the other it is receiving.  That example is not receiving on one UART from two "producers".  If you were to add another "producer" then you would connect it to a different UART with a different IRQ, ISR, and FIFO.

Comment: By producers, I meant sources of sending data; you're not just limited to one source be it a terminal - you have more than one and they're firing the same IRQ, which means the same Fifo buffer is being accessed by either sources

Comment: That code you linked to show no low level IRQ stuff. You need to show that if that is what you ask about. It simply shows some kind of event handlers, one for BLE recived data and one for UART received data. It simply forwards BLE received data for UART transmission and UART received data for BLE transmission. Sure, in hardware, the UART may have single IRQ for signaling about received data byte having arrived and being ready to transmit next data byte, that is normal.

Answer (score 2):

You would of course implement an interface that prevents the two tasks from accessing the resource in a way that makes no sense and only allow access in a way that does make sense.

So don't allow interleaved byte access to UART, but allow accessing UART to send whole messages.

You could protect UART with a e.g. mutex so each task waits until a complete message is sent. The messages could be put into FIFO so each task can simply send a message without blocking and then UART interrupt code empties FIFO in the background. Like, exactly the same way you would do it without an RTOS.

Also, there's no one way of doing this, someone else might have a better idea, like have a guard task for the resource and let a single task handle the UART.

Comment: 1) but it's not that the two *tasks* are accessing the source, rather one task receives stuff from the ISR over a Queue. Just two producers firing the same UART interrupt around the same time: sending data from each source around the same time. 2) But the UART ISR is fired for each byte entered. How do I make it so that it's only fired once a end of data byte is sent? 3) Maybe I'm misunderstanding you but if two IRQs occur around the same time with same priority, I don't see how race condition could arise

Comment: So now I don't follow. What do you mean by two producers firing same UART ISR? You can receive one byte at a time from one source? Do you have two UARTs, both receiving into same FIFO? Who sends data where? Yes, most UARTs do fire an ISR after receiving each byte. Edit your question better and I will edit my answer then.

Comment: Edited the description. Hope it's clearer now. I have two producers triggering the same UART handler, which means accessing the same Fifo.

Comment: My answer still applies. Whatever you do, you must make sure that full messages from one task are sent as full messages over the UART if that is what you want. Whatever it may mean to be a full message, like a packet of data or a line of text.

Comment: are you referring to a thread by task? if yes, can we not use the word task because this seems to be causing some confusion here. Messages are sent from within the ISR handler to a main thread

Comment: Your code uses the word task for threads too. It also does not reflect the dual producer situation you are describing.

Comment: I wanted to clarify not cause I am not fine with the wordings but I am having trouble understanding

Comment: I also have trouble understanding if this is about transmitting or receiving data over UART, as why would you receive data on IRQs that threads on same MCU are sending? Is there an external loopback that routes sent bytes back for receiving?

Comment: I have referenced a link to nordic's example for the reference: it sends data from the app through UART service, and through COM listener which is the terminal. So, now you have two "sources" for sending the bytes over UART and one MCU with one UART peripheral being used. When a byte is sent from either source, the same IRQ handler is invoked. 1) How would you keep the bytes from each "source" separate and not merged? 2) How would you handle the situation where bytes are sent around the same time?

Answer (score 2):

What constitutes a 'producer' in this context? Is it a hardware uart peripheral? In which case producer A & B are two uart peripherals. Therefore you'd need two instances of the UART object which would also imply two fifos. If the two uart peripherals share an interrupt (unusual for a single chip micro, but might be the case if an external multi uart chip is used), then the irq handler needs to determine which actual uart has interrupted, then call the irq() method on the relevant UART object.

If you need an example of this, then look at the Arduino core code. It implements support for multiple hardware uarts with circular buffers for send/receive written in C++ for an embedded platform.

If I'm way off the mark regarding what you actually want to do, then reframe your question with concrete terms rather than fluffy comp-sci terms like 'producer/consumer' which serve only to obfuscate the issue. Tell us where the data is coming from, via what peripheral etc. It wouldn't hurt to tell us the microcontroller you're using. That way we can form a concrete view of the system and be able to advise you. And don't start a question with So.....

Comment: Producer could be 1) minicom sending bytes to the device invoking the UART IRQ handler 2) UART service sending bytes which invokes the UART IRQ handler but I wouldn't want to use two different uart instances. I have pasted a reference link of how nordic does

Comment: Does this mean you want to send and receive data from a hardware uart Peripheral? In which case you need two fifos as you have effectively two independant data streams. Arduino has a core for nrf52 that implements circular buffers for uart send/receive. Refer to that code for inspiration.

Comment: Yes. But in the nordic's example, both streams invoke the same IRQ handler, meaning the same Fifo is used.

Comment: @jazzy. Have you stepped through the nordic code to support your assertion? You have two streams - send and receive asynchronous to each other, so how could you share a fifo? I think you’re overlooking a common solution to a common problem due to a misunderstanding. On a nrf52 you've got plenty of ram, so no need to skimp on trying to share a fifo. I did things like that 30 years ago for half duplex comms on chips with 128 bytes of ram.

Comment: but nothing is stopping you from *sending* the data from terminal and BLE service to the device at the same time, no? meaning the device is receiving possibly two interrupts

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem so here's what I did:

I used a RAM FIFO with a mutex. Any producer that wants to write to the uart gets a lock on the mutex, pushes the whole message into the fifo, and releases the lock. This ensures each message is put into the fifo without being interleaved with other messages.

Then, after putting the message into the FIFO, it triggers (in software) the UART transmit interrupt. This is the interrupt that is usually called when the hardware UART FIFO needs filling. So, it reads from the RAM FIFO and fills the UART hardware FIFO, then returns, and the interrupt is triggered again when the UART needs more data.

So, each producer pushes data into a RAM FIFO without touching the UART hardware. And an interrupt pulls from that FIFO and fills the UART hardware FIFO with the data. There is only one UART transmit interrupt, of course.

Comment: I think your point does make sense but are you polling for the UART data if you wanna write to a RAM FIFO, to begin with?

Comment: No, no polling, but I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Say you send a byte from a terminal...how would the program know when to read it if you aren't using an interrupt and polling?

Comment: Well, the question talks about sending bytes over UART, not receiving bytes over UART

Comment: sending and reception go hand in hand, no? what's the point of sending something you can't even receive? Hence my question: how are you even storing the BYTE RECEIVED into a RAM FIFO. If you don't know how to receive it, I'm not sure if you are justifying your point

Comment: Sending and receiving are different because you're in control of when you send but not when you receive. So is the question about sending or receiving? Also a UART can only receive from one source since there's only one connection, it's not ethernet...

Comment: I wouldn't have trouble sending data but more so handling data being sent from two different sources on the device. So your point does make sense to store into a RAM FIFO with a mutex and once the message is done sending, trigger an interrupt but i'm unclear on the actual flow...

Comment: You can also have each task hold a mutex on the uart itself, so only one task can send at any given time, but then they will hold the mutex for a longer time because uart is slow. I used the FIFO so the tasks post their messages in the fifo, which is fast, so they don't hold the mutex lock for long.

Comment: Can we first clarify as to how the device knows when the data is received to it could be written to the FIFO in RAM? I know only know two approaches: interrupt and polling. You're using neither. You have stuff sitting in your UART's `DR`. How do you know when to pull off of it?

Comment: If it's about receiving and not sending, then the uart interrupt does the job.

Comment: yes, receiving from two different sources though. How does the interrupt handle the IRQ request coming from each source?

Comment: How do you receive from 2 different sources using the same uart? You got a mux on the pin to switch the signals?

Comment: After looking further into the examples, it looks to me UART service calls a Service handler which in itself puts stuff on the UART write register, hence firing a UART IRQ handler, whereas if you were to send stuff from minicom, you're storing stuff right into the UART read register, which fires a UART IRQ handler. Makes sense? Given that's the case, they're still firing the same IRQ handler...so assuming that's the case, what happens when they're firing around the same time? One waits till the next one is done executing?

Comment: This makes no sense;

Comment: well, I just told you what I looked up. It's for you to believe or not

Comment: "storing stuff right into the UART read register" makes no sense, why would you write to the read register? Does it even do anything?

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. *I'm* not storing myself explicitly in the application - I'm merely reading off of it inside the IRQ handler.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have two "producers" (senders) transmitting bytes into the RxD line of a single UART, if you don't synchronize them. Even if both of them would only send 1-byte (5 to 8 bits) messages, the bytes would get corrupted if sent at overlapping times.

Due to the lack of clarity in your question, but from some comments, I conclude that you will have two separated hardware channels that receive the bytes from the producers. But you assume that both channels trigger the same interrupt.

In this case the interrupt logic of your microcontroller has some means of telling you **which** channel has received a byte. And you could read it and use it to assemble the respective message.